# OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility - User Mapping, MetadataException OpsHub-014371

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am using the OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility and when I go to the User Mapping screen, I receive the following dialog box:

Error
"com.opshub.eai.metadata.MetadataException: OpsHub-014371: Could not instantiate metadata implementation for For User List | TFS Source 1437692124799 ALM TFS 1437692124807, due to (301)Moved Permanently"

Also, I installed the utility on multiple computers, tried connecting to different TFS 2010 instances, but always receive similar error messages.

Does anyone have any experience troubleshooting this issue?

Comment: Hi, is your on-prem TFS installed over HTTPS?

Comment: No. I can only connect using HTTP.

Comment: Hi, most likely the issue is pertaining the current location of your TFS instance. The server seems to be responding that the URL is no longer served at that location, instead is redirected to another location. Can you please share the logs from C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs with us. We'll try to see if any workaround is possible

Comment: Sure. How can I get the logs to you?

Comment: Please send them to ovsmu@opshub.com